# What makes Apache Pig an ETL tool?

Tags: apache-pig, etl

I would like if anyone can explain me what makes Apache Pig an ETL tool and what the opposite would be. I understand that ETL means, extract, transform and load the data, which Pig does so, but so does other platforms like Flink, Spark and R (you get the data, perform some operations and load it somewhere else) and I could not find any information saying those tools are also considered ETL. Maybe I am missing something? Maybe I do not fully understand what does ETL means? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you told ETL tool means , the tool which can be used for Extracting , transforming , and loading data.And for ETL tool we will have a UI for visual development eg: Informatica/Datastage. I am not sure whether we can include PIG as 'tool' for ETL purpose. But surely it can be used for ETL process.PIG/HIVE are the client side libraries for this purpose.